# Autoreply to include original message

Tags: sieve, auto-reply

I have a linux postfix server with roundcube, dovecot and sieve installed.

I want to reply to messages with a certain subject with a message and the original message quoted.

Is there a macro/variable for the message body?

So I can create a template like:

```
Your order shown below has been recieved and will be processed within the next 2 days 
[body]
```

Comment: You generally don't want that, as then spammers can use your autoresponder to deliver their spam messages.

Comment: In this case it is not relevant, as the spammer will have to guess the recipient, subject and some content from the message.

Comment: Why does the spammer have to guess?  If they know that "sales@example.com" replies to every received message with the complete original body content, then they just send thousands of messages to that sales address with a fake sender address that is the intended recipient of the spam. This is not theoretical... now your mail server gets blacklisted for distributing spam.

Comment: In this case it is one specific sender, sending a message to a specific receiver with a specific subject, and the reply goes to that specific sender.

Comment: Actually, due to some stupid rule, each quarter the company sends us a list of invoices, we have to confirm we have received the stuff.

Comment: So we (I) blindly quote their message back to them, adding "yes, we have received the items from the above mentioned invoices". This is the exact text they tell us to answer with. I guess it is some stupid attempt to prevent sellers to write false invoices for fraudulent purposes. So I'd like a robot to answer this automatically.

Comment: So what happens when 10 different senders send a spam message to this email address? Those senders get their own message back, right? Now assume the sender's email is faked and one of those is your personal email at home, and your mother's, etc. Where are those "reply" messages going to end up?

Comment: You are clearly not reading my comments.

Comment: The messages only are picked up if the sender domain is right, the subject matches a strict subset, and is therefore only sent to that domain.

Comment: OK, it was not clear that you actually check the sender domain